# I want to convert as below via preg_replace

Tags: preg-replace, preg-match

I want to convert as below via preg_replace.
How can i know answer??

```
preg_replace($pattern, "$2/$1", "One001Two111Three");
```

result> Three/Two111/One001

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), it's much more simple than preg_replace and it works with any number of elements:

```
$str = "One001Two111Three";
$res = implode('/', array_reverse(preg_split('/(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])/', $str)));
echo $res,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
Three/Two111/One001
```

The regex `/(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])/` splits on boundary between a digit and a capital letter, [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) reverse the order of the array given by preg_split, then the elements of reversed array are joined by [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with a `/`

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "One001Two111Three";
$result = preg_replace('/^(.*?\d+)(.*?\d+)(.*?)$/im', '$3/$2/$1', $string );
echo $result;
```

**RESULT:** `Three/Two111/One001`

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/vjaOpF)</kbd>

**EXPLANATION:**

```
^(.*?\d+)(.*?\d+)(.*?)$
-----------------------

Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn't match line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks; Greedy quantifiers; Regex syntax only

Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed) «^»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?\d+)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(.*?\d+)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) (line feed) «$»

$3/$2/$1

Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 3 «$3»
Insert the character “/” literally «/»
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 2 «$2»
Insert the character “/” literally «/»
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1 «$1»
```